# The TLS connection was non-properly terminated in kubernetes

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I am doing an apt-get update  for installing Kubernetes and I get this message
https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial Release
Could not handshake: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

and ofcourse later in the process; ""The repository 'http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial Release' does not have a Release file"

I have the proxies set correctly:

1  in **etc-apt-apt.conf.d -proxy.conf**
*Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
and proxies are set for https_proxy; http_proxy and ftp_proxy*

2. and in **

> **etc conf I have disabled ipv6
> net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
> net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
> net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1**

**

Can someone please help me understand what other proxies etc are missing to avoid the TLS error.

Comment: Can you provide more information about environment you are working on, any tutorial you had used/ steps you took so far ?

Comment: Tried multiple sites:
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-install-kubernetes-kubeadm/
http://pwittrock.github.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/
The machine is on a corporate network so behind a firewall.

Comment: apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https             curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -              
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list          
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main               
EOF      
apt-get update                    *** this fails               
apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue:
This was an issue due to be being behind a firewall
The apt-key before the apt-get update instruction was the issue

By rerunning the apt-key using
**"curl -sSL 

'http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xBBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886' 

| sudo apt-key add - "**

instead of the original instruction
**curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -**

Full set of instructions

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install docker.io
3. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl
4. ***curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add –***
5. cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
6. deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
7. EOF
8. sudo apt-get update: